# 20 period moving average calculation for nifty Index Price

Tags: php, mysql

- nifty is a stock Index for National stock Exchange of India. *

I have a data base named "livedata" in which table name is `nifty` this is a stock index for National Stock Exchange of India. I have a row named

ID as Primary Key, time as timestamp, cmp for the specific "nifty" Stock Index.. During the day (09:15:01 A.M. to 03:29:59 P.M.)in a single minute

(1) I receive around 5 Trade entries.

Example:-

```
ID |        time        |     cmp | 
-----------------------------------
1  |2014-10-17 10:55:05 | 7743.85 | 
2  |2014-10-17 10:55:15 | 7743.55 | 
3  |2014-10-17 10:55:22 | 7743.35 | 
4  |2014-10-17 10:55:34 | 7744.85 | 
5  |2014-10-17 10:55:45 | 7743.35 | 
6  |2014-10-17 10:55:56 | 7743.25 | this should be the last / closing trade Entry.
7  |2014-10-17 10:56:17 | 7743.15 | 
8  |2014-10-17 10:56:25 | 7742.85 | 
9  |2014-10-17 10:56:35 | 7742.25 | 
10 |2014-10-17 10:56:45 | 7743.35 | 
11 |2014-10-17 10:56:55 | 7742.65 | this should be the last / closing trade Entry.
12 |2014-10-17 10:57:23 | 7743.55 | 
13 |2014-10-17 10:57:37 | 7744.85 | 
14 |2014-10-17 10:57:46 | 7743.55 | 
15 |2014-10-17 10:57:53 | 7741.85 | 
16 |2014-10-17 10:57:56 | 7742.45 | this should be the last / closing trade Entry.
17 |2014-10-17 10:58:05 | 7743.85 | 
18 |2014-10-17 10:58:17 | 7743.55 | 
19 |2014-10-17 10:58:29 | 7743.35 | 
20 |2014-10-17 10:58:37 | 7744.85 | 
21 |2014-10-17 10:58:48 | 7743.35 | 
22 |2014-10-17 10:58:56 | 7743.25 | this should be the last / closing trade Entry.
23 |2014-10-17 10:59:17 | 7743.15 | 
24 |2014-10-17 10:59:21 | 7742.85 | 
25 |2014-10-17 10:59:33 | 7742.25 | 
26 |2014-10-17 10:59:43 | 7743.35 | 
27 |2014-10-17 10:59:50 | 7742.65 | 
28 |2014-10-17 10:59:57 | 7743.55 | this should be the last / closing trade Entry.
29 |2014-10-17 10:60:17 | 7744.85 | 
30 |2014-10-17 10:60:25 | 7743.55 | 
31 |2014-10-17 10:60:36 | 7741.85 | 
32 |2014-10-17 10:60:47 | 7742.45 |this should be the last / closing trade Entry.
```

I wanted to Calculate Moving Average Based on the last / closing price for every minute. for this out of many entries in a single (1) minute, I

require only last trade entry.
Example base Desired Result:-

```
ID |          time      |     cmp |
-----------------------------------
6  |2014-10-17 10:55:56 | 7743.25 | 
11 |2014-10-17 10:56:55 | 7742.65 | 
16 |2014-10-17 10:57:56 | 7742.45 | 
22 |2014-10-17 10:58:56 | 7743.25 | 
28 |2014-10-17 10:59:57 | 7743.55 | 
32 |2014-10-17 10:60:47 | 7742.45 |
```

Ex. (Moving Average = ADD 20 period i.e. last trade entry of every minute for last 20 minutes & divide it by 20. The value should come up on the

frontend may be using $result= mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error()); please suggest..

If I want to get the last entry of the each minute how do I write the PHP code?  Right now I am fetching entries using

```
$query= "SELECT FROM nifty WHERE time BETWEEN '2014-10-17 10:55:05' AND '2014-10-17 10:60:47'";
```

Actual result:-

```
ID      Date Stamp        CMP
1   2014-10-17 10:55:05 7743.85
2   2014-10-17 10:55:14 7743.75
3   2014-10-17 10:55:18 7745.30
4   2014-10-17 10:55:21 7745.35
5   2014-10-17 10:55:32 7745.10
6   2014-10-17 10:55:36 7744.85
7   2014-10-17 10:55:46 7744.40
8   2014-10-17 10:55:50 7744.70
9   2014-10-17 10:55:59 7745.60 this should be the last / closing trade Entry.
10  2014-10-17 10:56:06 7745.80
11  2014-10-17 10:56:11 7745.40
12  2014-10-17 10:56:23 7746.50
13  2014-10-17 10:56:32 7747.30
14  2014-10-17 10:56:34 7747.35
15  2014-10-17 10:56:41 7747.65
16  2014-10-17 10:56:52 7747.80
17  2014-10-17 10:56:56 7748.20 this should be the last / closing trade Entry.
18  2014-10-17 10:57:01 7747.80
19  2014-10-17 10:57:13 7747.75
20  2014-10-17 10:57:16 7747.55
21  2014-10-17 10:57:28 7747.50
22  2014-10-17 10:57:32 7746.95
23  2014-10-17 10:57:38 7746.55
24  2014-10-17 10:57:40 7746.70
25  2014-10-17 10:57:50 7747.25
26  2014-10-17 10:57:58 7746.55 this should be the last / closing trade Entry.
27  2014-10-17 10:58:09 7746.70
28  2014-10-17 10:58:11 7746.90
29  2014-10-17 10:58:17 7747.20
30  2014-10-17 10:58:26 7746.75
31  2014-10-17 10:58:33 7746.70
32  2014-10-17 10:58:37 7746.55 this should be the last / closing trade Entry.
33  2014-10-17 11:30:28 7748.35
34  2014-10-17 11:30:32 7748.95
35  2014-10-17 11:30:40 7749.95
36  2014-10-17 11:30:45 7749.05
37  2014-10-17 11:30:58 7748.95 this should be the last / closing trade Entry.
38  2014-10-17 11:31:03 7748.80
39  2014-10-17 11:31:08 7749.90
40  2014-10-17 11:31:12 7751.80
41  2014-10-17 11:31:26 7752.70
42  2014-10-17 11:31:33 7753.80
43  2014-10-17 11:31:33 7753.60
44  2014-10-17 11:31:39 7752.55
45  2014-10-17 11:31:50 7752.65
46  2014-10-17 11:31:56 7754.60 this should be the last / closing trade Entry.
47  2014-10-17 11:32:18 7755.15
48  2014-10-17 11:32:18 7755.35
49  2014-10-17 11:32:26 7755.25
50  2014-10-17 11:32:36 7754.45
51  2014-10-17 11:32:40 7754.90
52  2014-10-17 11:32:56 7754.40 this should be the last / closing trade Entry.
53  2014-10-17 11:33:10 7754.35
54  2014-10-17 11:33:12 7753.65
55  2014-10-17 11:33:15 7753.45
56  2014-10-17 11:33:22 7753.50
57  2014-10-17 11:33:25 7753.35
58  2014-10-17 11:33:34 7753.45
59  2014-10-17 11:33:39 7754.20
60  2014-10-17 11:33:49 7756.35
61  2014-10-17 11:33:50 7755.65
62  2014-10-17 11:33:54 7757.15 this should be the last / closing trade Entry.
63  2014-10-17 11:34:01 7759.05
```

Can we use loop, while, do while for this?
Please help met to solve this many thanks in advance.

Results expected using `SELECT LOOP WHILE DO WHILE` etc.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems have you run into?
Please read [How to ask questions on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Since when was there a `10:60` ?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not support analytic functions, which make tasks of this sort much more difficult than it would be in many other RDBMS engines.

Whilst one *can* still use a pure set-based SQL approach, that would be both much harder to understand and probably far less efficient than a little short-cut using a [user variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/user-variables.html):

```sql
SELECT AVG(cmp) FROM (
    SELECT   cmp, @t:=time - INTERVAL SECOND(time) SECOND
    FROM     nifty, (SELECT @t:=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) init
    WHERE    time < @t
    ORDER BY time DESC
    LIMIT    20
) x
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/51affb/1).

The outer query ought to be fairly self-explanatory: it just takes the mean of the `cmp` values from the inner query.

The inner query moves backwards over the `nifty` table, thanks to its `ORDER BY` clause; using variable `@t` to keep track of the latest minute for which we have already accounted, the `WHERE` clause ensures that only entries preceding that minute are considered next—whilst the second term in the `SELECT` list updates `@t` to the start of the found minute whenever a match is found.  Finally the `LIMIT` clause ensures that the inner query is terminated once the 20th record has been found.

This query would be computed most efficiently if there exists a compound index of which `(time, cmp)` are the leftmost columns, in that order.  For example:

```sql
ALTER TABLE nifty ADD INDEX (time, cmp)
```